# setState function not working In react when called inside componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-lifecycle

I am importing a json file into my react app for the data and using setState function as shown in the code below

```
import ruleSets from './db.json'
class App extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    ruleSets.map((element)=>{
      if(element.phase ==="post_auth"){
        this.setState({
          postAuthRuleSets: element,
        })
      }
      else if(element.phase === "pre_auth"){
        this.setState({
          preAuthRuleSets:element
        })
      }
    })
  }


  constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
    this.state={
      postAuthRuleSets:null,
      preAuthRuleSets:null
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <h1>hello</h1>
    {this.postAuthRuleSets.rules?.length>0 ? 
    this.postAuthRuleSets.rules.map((element) => <h1> {element.id}</h1>):
    <h1>not fetching data</h1>}
    </div>)
  }
}
export default App;
```

but error is showing in the console because the variables I'm looping through are pointing null which means setState is not working.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Why are you  using class component till now , switch to the functional component

Comment: How would switching to a function component solve their issue?

Comment: @Asskay: what's the structure of the json data? Based on the fact you do `ruleSets.map` it must be an array at the top level, but what's inside the array? And you mentioned an error; what's the error?

Answer (score 1):

```
{this.postAuthRuleSets.rules?.length>0
```

This is accessing a property that does not exist: `this.postAuthRulesSets`. It should be accessing the state, as in `this.state.postAuthRulesSets`. Also keep in mind that it will be null during the first render, so make sure to use optional chaining at all necessary spots:

```
{this.state.postAuthRuleSets?.rules?.length > 0
```

Another improvement you can do is to move the logic out of of componentDidMount and into the constructor. Everything you're doing is synchronous, so there's no need to wait until after the component is already mounted. This change will mean you only need to render once instead of twice, and there will be no possibility of `this.state.postAuthRuleSets` being null

```
constructor(props,context){
  super(props,context);
  this.state={
    postAuthRuleSets: ruleSets.find(element => element.phase === "post_auth"),
    preAuthRuleSets: ruleSets.find(element => element.phase === "pre_auth")
  }
}
```